# TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS() gives not random results

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to use `SELECT id FROM table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1)` for selecting 1 random row, but I always get first row, so it's not random. 
But I realized that I get this problem only with the newly created table, because same query for the old table gives correct random results. I already tried to reindex table with this problem, but unfortunately it didn't help.

So, how can I get correct random output using `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1)`?

Comment: I cannot find `SYSTEM_ROWS` as `sampling_method` in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html) and you query also doesn't work on my 9.6.5 test server (and also on SQL Fiddle's 9.6.6) -- "ERROR:  tablesample method system_rows does not exist". Do you have this from any extension or so? It might be worth mentioning this.

Comment: I guess I found it ["tsm_system_rows"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tsm-system-rows.html), right? You've read "(...) the sample is not completely random but may be subject to clustering effects, especially if only a small number of rows are requested."? Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: @stickybit I already thought about this, but I also think that "not completely random" and "every time absolutely same row" are different things. Anyway now I will try to increase the number of rows in my table.

Comment: I don't know the logic behind this in detail, but if I understand it right, the randomness is limited to the page chosen. After that, maybe a deterministic approach is used, like the _n_ first records in the chosen pages. It might well be, that a small table, that fits in one page will result in always the same page, and therefore the same row again and again.

Comment: @stickybit indeed, it just depends on the page size. So, I will look for another solution for the fast random select...

Comment: Could it be that the table has only one 8K block? That would explain the behavior.

Comment: Any solution for that? Same problem here..